# serializing byte array for transaction data

Tags: raw-transaction, python, pyethereum

I've upgraded from python 2 to python 3 and some code that used to work is now broken.  I can't seem to fix it.  Any suggestions?

Worked in python 2

```
# Convert hex string to byte array
hex_string = "0x00012345...."
data_bytearray = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string.replace("0x", ""))

# Then I pass data_bytearray into transactions.Transaction and it works.  
try:
    return {'error': False, 'sign': rlp.encode(transactions.Transaction(nonce, gasPrice_int, gas_int, to, value, data_bytearray).sign(privkey)).encode('hex')}
except Exception as msg:
    return {'error': True, 'message': msg}
```

Same code doesn't work in python 3 and note the byte array data type has changed to

```
<class 'bytearray'>   # python 3 produces this from bytearray.fromhex
<type 'bytearray'>    # python 2 produces this from bytearray.fromhex
```

I get the following error:

```
{'error': True, 'message': ObjectSerializationError('Serialization failed because of field data ("Object is not a serializable (<class \'bytearray\'>)")',)}
```

I tried serializing the output using pickle, but got another error:

```
import pickle
data_bytearray = pickle.dumps(data_bytearray)

{'error': True, 'message': AttributeError("'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'",)}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Solution:

```
try:
    data_hex_with0xRemoved = data_hex.replace("0x", "")
    # If I use bytearray.fromhex, it results in {'error': True, 'message': ObjectSerializationError('Serialization failed because of field data ("Object is not a serializable (<class \'bytearray\'>)")',)}
    # data = bytearray.fromhex('deadbeef')
    # So instead I use bytes.fromhex
    data = bytes.fromhex(data_hex_with0xRemoved)
    unsigned_transaction = transactions.Transaction(nonce, gasPrice_int, gas_int, to, value, data)
    raw_transaction_bytes = rlp.encode(unsigned_transaction.sign(privkey))
    raw_transaction_hex = Web3.toHex(raw_transaction_bytes)
    raw_transaction_hex_0xRemoved = raw_transaction_hex.replace("0x", "")
    return {'error': False, 'sign': raw_transaction_hex_0xRemoved}
except Exception as msg:
    return {'error': True, 'message': msg}
```

Comment: Have you tried `bytes` instead of `bytearray`? Also, you might like: `data_bytes = Web3.toBytes(hexstr="0x00012345")` from web3.py

Comment: Yes both bytes and Web3.toBytes gave me a similar error to pickle.dumps:  {'error': True, 'message': AttributeError("'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'",)}.

Comment: This is not really a solution, but you could call a py2 script that performs this operation and returns the value to py3 script.  I ran into this same problem and had too many more important battles to pick so I took the quick workaround that allowed me to move on to more important things.  I'm curious about the right way to do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

```
try:
    unsigned_transaction = transactions.Transaction(nonce, gasPrice_int, gas_int, to, value, data_bytearray)
    raw_transaction = rlp.encode(unsigned_transaction.sign(privkey))
    return {'error': False, 'sign': Web3.toHex(raw_transaction)}
except Exception as msg:
    return {'error': True, 'message': msg}
```

The only notable change is from `raw_transaction.encode('hex')` to `Web3.toHex(raw_transaction)`.

The other differences from the original line were simply to reduce the amount of logic per line.

---

## Why?

> both bytes and Web3.toBytes gave me a similar error to pickle.dumps: `{'error': True, 'message': AttributeError("'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'",)}`

This ^ comment was the most helpful, although it doesn't explain why you don't get that same error with `bytearray` (I think you should). See:

```
In [1]: b'\xaf'.encode('hex')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

In [2]: bytearray(b'\xaf').encode('hex')
AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

This doesn't really have anything to do with Ethereum, only with learning how encoding and pickling works in Python 3. For example, I would expect the following to behave exactly as the first code sample from the question does:

```
try:
    return {'error': False, 'sign': bytearray(b'\xaf').encode('hex')}
except Exception as msg:
    return {'error': True, 'message': msg}
```

Encoding in Python 2 had a sloppy API, and permitted people to do nonsensical things, like "encode" binary data (which is already encoded, being binary). So, `encode()` was removed from the Python 3 `bytes` type altogether. If you want to convert `bytes` to hex in Python 3, there are a few ways to do it:

### My personal favorite option

```
> Web3.toHex(b'\xaf')
'0xaf'
```

### Alternatively, in Python 3.5+, you can use:

```
> b'\xaf'.hex()
'af'
# note that you don't get the "0x" prefix
```

### Another built-in option is binascii

```
> import binascii
> hex_in_bytes = binascii.hexlify(b'\xaf')
b'af'

# binascii made the nonsensical choice to return the hex value in a `bytes` type
# which you can fix up by decoding to a string

> hex_in_bytes.decode('utf8')
'af'
```

*(All of these except `Web3` work with `bytearray` as well).*

Comment: You were right, the problems i ran into were all related to my misunderstandings around python 3 and not ethereum.  Thanks for breaking this down for me.  I posted the final code I went with above.  I ended up having to use bytes.fromhex instead of bytearray.fromhex for the reason listed above.

Comment: Got it, you may also like `data = Web3.toBytes(hexstr=data_hex)`.